# Angular4 - How to set select option value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a select list with the code -

```
<select (change)='onGroupChange($event)'>
    <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value={{group.group_name}}>
        {{group.group_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now I have a group name value saved as a different variable and I want to set that as the select list value if it matches any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<select (change)='onGroupChange($event)'>
    <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value={{group.group_name}} [selected]="group.group_name==myVariable">
        {{group.group_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is `myVariable` here?

Comment: "Now I have a group name value saved as a different variable and I want to set that as the select list value if it matches any."  myVariable is the 'different variable'.

Answer (score 6):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup" (ngModelChange)="onGroupChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.group_name">
    {{group.group_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: this works. But the only issue is that if it doesn't matches any value, then it doesn't select the first value by default. The answer given by @Michael takes care of that scenario.